# MusicAlbum duration in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, duration

How do I go about adding a music album duration in schema.org?

What's the rationale for the lack of duration in type `MusicAlbum`? If something defines an album is its length, but no duration is available unless an album is tagged as `MusicRelease`.

There is `timeRequired`, but it is also described as "approximate or typical time it usually takes to work with or through the content", but music album are anything but approximates.

How do you tag duration in music album without having to markup a `MusicRelease`?

Answer (score 1):

the type `MusicAlbum` has the property `albumRelease` that can be extended with the embedded type `MusicRelease` which in turn has the property `duration` that you need. Markup example:

```js
{
"@context":"https://schema.org",
"@type":"MusicAlbum",
    ...
"albumRelease":{
"@type": "MusicRelease",
"duration":"..."
},
    ...
}
```

In addition to the response from LizardKG dated January 13, 2024.

> Thank you nikant25. I get that it has to be marked as MusicRelease,
> but when I validate in schema.org I get the album split in different
> boxes rather than just one validation for album. For example, I get a
> box for MusicRelease, another for MusicAlbum, and another one for
> MusicRecordings. I even get different separated results within the
> MusicRelease box. Is this normal. You can see it here album's results

Your structured data has markup for two separate top-level types `MusicRelease` and the separate type `MusicAlbum`. Each document, including an HTML document such as a web page, can have only one content subject. It is a good idea to create the most appropriate top-level type in your structured data to represent the subject of the content. Of course, there can only be one top-level type, because the content has only one subject. Thus, structured data should represent the structure of the HTML document and this is probably reflected in the name STRUCTURED data.

Your main content represents the subject such as the music album. But your structured data represents 20 separate top-level types that share the juice among themselves.

In addition, your SD is created in the microdate format, which is highly dependent on the validity of the HTML source code in which the microdate is installed. But your source code has **[invalid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.venciclopedia.org%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DEl_amor_ya_no_existe)**, including critical errors like *Duplicate ID* and microdata errors, e.g.:

> Error: The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a
> property of any item.

Comment: Thank you nikant25. I get that it has to be marked as MusicRelease, but when I validate in schema.org I get the album split in different boxes rather than just one validation for album. For example, I get a box for MusicRelease, another for MusicAlbum, and another one for MusicRecordings. I even get different separated results within the MusicRelease box. Is this normal. You can see it here [album's results](https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.venciclopedia.org%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DEl_amor_ya_no_existe)

Comment: @LizardKG: Your example seems to miss the `albumRelease` property (which links the `MusicRelease` from the `MusicAlbum`).

Comment: @LizardKG I have made an addition to my post with an explanation for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and pointing out problems. I appreciate it. One problem is that, in my opinion, schema's properties don't completely match real albums to MusicAlbum. For example, on my site, I list catalog numbers, but I can't tag them because only MusicRelease has that property. But when I call it I get two different outputs. I'm gonna look in my code. Maybe there's another MusicRelease somewhere that is corrupting my code. First I'll try the solutions provided.

Comment: Not having luck with my microformat. To add catalogNumber within a MusicAlbum I have to add MusicRelease to the container.  

`{| itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicAlbum"`  

So this works  

`itemprop="numTracks"`  

But catalog needs:  

`|-  itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/MusicRelease
...
| itemprop="catalogNumber"`  

MusicRelease then creates a second box in the validator and two boxes within because I also tag recordLabel. 


[Validator](https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.venciclopedia.org%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DMelissa_(disco))

Comment: A type cannot create structured data on its own. Most likely the reason is in your CMS or your PHP. Invalid HTML interferes with the parsing of your SD.